how to disable yarn.node-labels.allow_market_type_node_label in EMR-7.0.0
In the latest EMR release 7.0.0: we find out that there is a new configuration:
yarn.node-labels.allow_market_type_node_label and when yarn.node-labels.enabled=true this configuration is also set to true and causes the task groups get labels corresponding to its markets: (SPOT, ON-DAMEND).
How could this configuration be set to false?
I try to set
"Configurations": [{
        "Classification": "yarn-site",
        "Properties": {
            "yarn.node-labels.allow_market_type_node_label": "false"
        }
    }
]

on cluster create but it did not work.
